# Using Query to select colum based on headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google

I have a sheet with a large table of data with a header for each column. I want to import a specific column to another sheet using the header name. I am using the below formula to do so (which has worked in the past).

`=QUERY(Schedule!D:BW, "SELECT" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(H1,Schedule!D1:BW1,0),4),1,""))`

However I keep getting the below error and can't figure out how to solve this.

`Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "SELECTD "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "select" ... "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ...`

Answer (score 2):

You have to place a space between SELECT and the column letter, resulting from that calculation.
The error: "SELECTD " said you something :)

I think that this will solve the problem:

```
=QUERY(Schedule!D:BW, "SELECT " & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(H1,Schedule!D1:BW1,0),4),1,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cover this by transposing the dataset so the headers are in the first column, use `matches` / regex to match the columns you want, then transpose it back to normal

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
   TRANSPOSE(A1:E),
   "where Col1 matches 'Header 1|Header 2|Header 5'"))
```

Nothing fancy required. If you have a set list of columns you want to return (e.g. in F2:F), you can use

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
   TRANSPOSE(A1:E),
   "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,F2:F)&"'"))
```

The TEXTJOIN will generate the `Header 1|Header 2|Header 3` stuff.